# Use common VirtualBox setup between users

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, .desktop

I want to solve the following use case: my wife and me (= two separate linux users) want to use THE SAME VirtualBox Windows10 virtual machine. 
So my idea is to have all VirtualBox settings under the user "vmuser" and start VirtualBox always in the vmuser environment.

Then in the folder /home/vmuser all the VirtualBox settings are set up.

On every user desktop I added a desktop file "VirtualBox.desktop" with the content:

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Comment=
 Exec=mate-terminal -- /bin/su vmuser -w QT_QPA_PLATFORM_THEME,DISPLAY,XDG_RUNTIME_DIR -c /usr/local/bin/startVirtualBox.sh
 GenericName=Go virtual
 Icon=virtualbox
 MimeType=
 Name=VirtualBox
 Path=
 StartupNotify=true
 Terminal=true
 TerminalOptions=
 Type=Application
 X-DBUS-ServiceName=
 X-DBUS-StartupType=
 X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
 X-KDE-Username=`
```

Clicking on this icon then launches the file `/usr/local/bin/startVirtualBox.sh`. The "-w" is for not replacing existing environment variables. I use "mate-terminal" because it is starting faster on my machine compared to "gome-terminal" but your mileage may vary.

For some to me yet unknown reason (I think the issue is the /bin/sh at the beginning but it does not work without) I need to define the environment variables this way:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 
 DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
 XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
 export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM
 export DISPLAY 
 export XAUTHORITY 
 export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 

 /usr/bin/VirtualBox
```

This solution works as expected despite some error messages during the start of VirtualBox in the extra console window:

```
Qt WARNING: QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 1002
Qt WARNING: Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

The user runtime directory is under control of the user who clicks the desktop icon (id=1000) and the VirtualBox process starts under the vmuser (user id = 1002). Ok.

But does anybody know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - I just got an idea.

- user A creates a VM, with the virtual HDD in a directory where both users have full access permissions
- shut the machine down
- user B creates a VM with identical properties, but doesn't create a new virtual HDD. Instead use the one created by user A.
- shut the machine down

**Warning**: you will always have to shut down the VM, don't let VirtualBox "save the state"

Comment: Good idea! I will try it out. Yes, then the snapshot functionality does not work out anymore.